# EnumResourceNames issue - unknown error

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop, kernel32

I was recently working with resources from secondary libraries/binary modules and encountered a strange error.

I have two native WinAPI references:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public extern static bool EnumResourceNames(IntPtr hModule, int lpszType, EnumResNameProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public extern static IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hFile, int dwFlags);
```

When I call LoadLibraryEx, I am getting the IntPtr instance - just what I need:

```
IntPtr x = WinApi.LoadLibraryEx(@"D:\Software\Reflector\Reflector.exe",IntPtr.Zero,2);
Debug.WriteLine(x.ToInt32());
```

However, when I try to enumerate icon resources (defined by the ID = 3):

```
Debug.WriteLine(WinApi.EnumResourceNames(x, 3, new EnumResNameProc(ListCallback), IntPtr.Zero));
Debug.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

I am getting this error code (returned by GetLastError):

**-532462766**

This usually means there is an unknown error, as far as I know, but I am just curious - what could be the problem with listing resources from the executable?

Comment: Is EnumResourceNames() actually returning false?  If it's returning true then the value of GetLastError() is meaningless.

Comment: Is it managed or unmanaged DLL?

Comment: It is returning False - it fails, apparently. This is a managed C# app calling an unmanaged DLL (kernel32).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-532462766 == 0xe0434352.  The last three hex pairs spell "CCR", a common trick that Microsoft programmers use to try to come up with an easily recognizable exception code.  The exact meaning is quite mysterious, beyond it being commonly associated with managed code and seemingly being very low level in a sub-system that doesn't normally fail to produce a meaningful managed exception.

There is an excellent candidate reason for that mysterious exception, your EnumResources pinvoke declaration is wrong.  The 2nd argument is IntPtr, not int.  That has some odds of going kaboom on a 64-bit operating system.

Please post back if you ever figure out what CCR means.

---

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            IntPtr module = LoadLibraryEx(@"C:\windows\system32\user32.dll", IntPtr.Zero, 2);
            if (module == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
            if (!EnumResourceNames(module, (IntPtr)3, new EnumResNameProc(ListCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
                throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static bool ListCallback(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr lp) {
        long idorname = (long)name;
        if (idorname >> 16 == 0) Console.WriteLine("#{0}", idorname);
        else Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(name));
        return true;
    }

    public delegate bool EnumResNameProc(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr type, IntPtr name, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static bool EnumResourceNames(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr type, EnumResNameProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hFile, int dwFlags);
}
```

Comment: I think CCR is one of the original names for the CLR.

Comment: Hm... According to the MSDN docs I have the correct signature for the methods I mentioned above. According to PInvoke.net (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.enumresourcenames) I am also using the correct signature. Still trying to figure out what CCR means.

Comment: No, it is definitely wrong.  Typical for pinvoke.net to get this both wrong and right in one page, there's no editor there to weed out the mistakes.  The SDK declaration uses LPCTSTR, that's a pointer.  IntPtr in managed code.  You use MAKEINTRESOURCE in C code to convert an int to a pointer.  You use (IntPtr)3 in your C# code to accomplish the same.

Comment: Even after I changed the parameter, I still get the same error. This is getting interesting.

Comment: I don't know, the callback is quite tricky too for the same reason.  You cannot make the 3rd argument a string.  I updated my post with code that works on my machine.

Comment: It works for me now that I used IntPtr, but I have another question - why do you have a 32 bit arithmetic shift?

Comment: Because that's how it distinguishes between named and numbered resource IDs.  Check out MAKEINTRESOURCE.  Btw, that should probably be a 16-bit shift.

Comment: Hans, in case you're curious I added an answer with a bit more information about where that error code is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant has it correct, but to elaborate on the error message, 0xe0434352 is the generic error code for a .NET exception. If you run this from the Visual Studio debugger you'll see that a `System.ArgumentException` is being raised when EnumResourceNames tries to invoke the callback. The error message is:

> The pointer passed in as a String must not be in the bottom 64K of the process's address space.

This exception gets caught by EnumResourceNames and turns into a failure. The solution, as Hans showed, is that the callback function must take the second and third parameters as IntPtr rather than string.